# missing log- and/or exception-messages from realm lib

Tags: android, realm, error-logging

I'm wondering if anybody did ever seen some **loglines** or **exception messages** from the **realm** DB in his app/project?

*Some background*: I'm new using realm. So sometimes I'm doing some mistakes (eg. trying to update a `DataModel extends RealmObject` outside a transaction). Of course these things will not work, but unfortunately I didn't see an error or a crash message of my mistake. In debug mode I can step over the line with my error and nothing happens...

I've tried using Crashlytics as described in the [docu](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#ndk-debugging), but no reports are submitted.

I am using:

- `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0` and `apply plugin: 'realm-android'`
- Android Studio
- all realm communication happens in a background thread (never on the ui-/main-thread)

Thank's for every hint.

Comment: Realm will throw an `IllegalStateException` in such a case. Sounds like a problem with your log files or logging setup?

Comment: Please use `1.1.1` it's a patch release over `1.1.0`

Comment: (...also, if you don't have Realm on the UI thread, how do you intend to query from the Realm?)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: I am developing my app in different layers - the storage layer performs his job on a background thread and notifies the UI with callbacks. (Pattern name: [Android Clean Architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/))

Comment: I'm still not sure how you're going to get your RealmObjects on the UI thread unless you use `copyFromRealm()` each time you need them :P

Comment: Yeah, that's the drawback: each layer defines his own model classes. So you have to map from storage model <-> domain model <-> view model. (Perhaps I'm loosing many cool realm features with that pattern?!)

Comment: Well, all that mapping is just fine as long as you don't have very large datasets :)  (although, yes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running into [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3173) that was fixed in 1.1.1 (using `insertOrUpdate()` did not check transaction state), so you should update to 1.1.1.

It's also worth noting that you should probably handle exceptions on your background threads if there are any, and log them if there are.

```
try {
    // do blah
} catch(Throwable e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred", e);
    throw e;
}
```

In fact, on background threads, you should probably do this

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    // do blah
} catch(Throwable e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred", e);
    throw e;
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you want to listen in on Realm's logs ( **THIS WILL BREAK IN 2.0.0** ), you can provide a `RealmLog` implementation.

```
io.realm.internal.log.RealmLog.add(new io.realm.internal.log.Logger() {
    public void v(String message) {
        Log.v("RealmLog", message);
    }

    public void v(String message, Throwable t) {
        Log.v("RealmLog", message, t);
    } 

    public void d(String message) {
        Log.d("RealmLog", message);
    }

    public void d(String message, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("RealmLog", message, t);
    } 

    public void i(String message) {
        Log.i("RealmLog", message);
    }

    public void i(String message, Throwable t) {
        Log.i("RealmLog", message, t);
    } 

    public void w(String message) {
        Log.w("RealmLog", message);
    }

    public void w(String message, Throwable t) {
        Log.w("RealmLog", message, t);
    } 

    public void e(String message) {
        Log.e("RealmLog", message);
    }

    public void e(String message, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("RealmLog", message, t);
    } 
});
```

You might not understand everything it tells you though, it's an internal log, after all.

Comment: Thanks! Surrounding my realm communication with a try-catch-block solved my problem! :) Now I see pretty nice error messages like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.`